# How to match array of mobile numbers with Mysql data?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to match this $string to mysql data to get mobile - owner name, owner fathers name, mothers name, Address etc.

```
$String =
"8800953627
 8900923628
 9910955622
 7770753623
 9800953625";
```

(mobile numbers seprated by line)

Comment: Start by splitting the string into an array, that you can bind into a WHERE IN clause in a SQL query, then execute the query and retrieve the results

Comment: What happen if i have 5000 mobile numbers to match, this will effect the server speed or not?

Comment: Yes it will, but by how much depends on your database and its indexes.... but if you want to display 5000 results, then rendering the page will take longer.... as things stand, your question doesn't say anything about your database, so we can't make any assumptions about it

Comment: So iterate over it. What did you try, that did not work as expected?

Comment: i had split mobile numbers into  array, but i dont know what to do afterwords, please show me an example how to do this, that would be a great help. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

coz you don't tell us your table structure your question is not very clear

the only guess I can imaging as start point is:

```
$String =
"8800953627
 8900923628
 9910955622
 7770753623
 9800953625";

$arr = explode("\n ",$String);
$arr = implode(",",$arr);

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'PDO connection error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, fathers_name, mother_name, address 
    FROM owners
    WHERE phone_number IN ( ? )' );
$sth->bindParam(1, $arr);
$sth->execute();

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo 'Name : '.$row['name'] ;
      echo 'Fathers name : '. $row['fathers_name'];
      echo 'Mothers name : '. $row['mothers_name'];
      echo 'Address : '.$row['address']. "\n";

    }
```

Comment: kim thankyou very much for your answer , what i have to put inside WHERE phone_number IN ( ? ) .

Comment: I did show that `$sth->bindParam(1, $arr);` read documentation more :-)))

Comment: Painful approach... especially given OP's comment about `What happen if i have 5000 mobile numbers to match`..... 5000 database queries will be incredibly slow when you could do it in 1 query.... build an IN statement and bind the whole array to the query

Comment: Mark thanks for your comment , i think  i will only show mobile numbers inside my page not whole detail of owner.

Answer (score 0):

first do

```
$numbers = explode('\n', $String);
```

to split the numbers into an array (btw you shouldn't start variable names with capital letter)
Then you could do

```
foreach($numbers as $number)
```

and do a mysql query with each iteration

Comment: Painful approach... especially given OP's comment about `What happen if i have 5000 mobile numbers to match`..... 5000 database queries will be incredibly slow when you could do it in 1 query

Comment: Yeah I didn't read the comments :l IN would be a much better way